Upper bound on higher order derivatives of $\frac{1}{v(t)}$
Suppose that $ v(t) >l>0$ and
$$
\vert v^{(k)}(t) \vert \leq c \frac{k!}{r^k}.
$$
Can we give an upper bound for
$$
(\frac{1}{v(t)})^{(k)}
$$
?
Attempt:
We first compute the first fourth order derivatives :
$$
(v^{-1})'= (-1)v^{-2} v' \quad \quad \quad
(v^{-1})''=  (-1)(-2)v^{-3} (v')^2 + (-1)v^{-2} v''\\
(v^{-1})''' 
= (-1)(-2)(-3) v^{-4} (v')^3 + (-1)(-2)v^{-3} 3v' v'' + (-1)v^{-2} v''' \\
(v^{-1})^{(4)} = (-1)(-2)(-3)(-4) v^{-5} (v')^4 + (-1)(-2)(-3)v^{-4} 6 (v')^2  v'' \\
+ (-1)(-2) v^{-3} ( 3 (v'')^2 + 4 v' v''') + (-1)v^{-2} v^{(4)}
$$
With observation, we find that
$$
(v^{-1})^{(n)} = \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^k k! v^{-k-1} (a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,1}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,1})} + a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,2}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,2})} + \cdots + a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,A(n,k)}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,A(n,k)})} )
$$
where
$\mathbf{n}_{k,i}$,$i = 1, 2 \cdots, A(n,k)$ denotes the $k$ component vector
$$
(n^{k,i}_1, n^{k,i}_2, \cdots, n^{k,i}_k),  
$$
which satisfies $ n^{k,i}_1 + n^{k,i}_2 + \cdots + n^{k,i}_k = n $.
$$
v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,i})} = v^{(n^{k,i}_1)} v^{(n^{k,i}_2)}\cdots v^{(n^{k,i}_k)}
$$
$A(n,k)$ denotes the number of  positive integer solutions of equation
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n
$$
here notice that, for two solutions $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ $(y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_n)$ only with difference in order, we see them as the same solution and count only once, for example, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$.
Now how can we represent the coefficients
$$
a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,i}}, \quad k=1,\cdots,n, \quad i = 1, 2,\cdots, A(n,k)
$$
and number $A(n,k)$?
(This is a transfer of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4998405/upper-bound-on-higher-order-derivatives-of-frac1vt)

To simplify writing and without loss of generality, consider the derivatives of $1/v$ at $t=0$. Your condition on the derivatives of $v$ implies that $v$ can be analytically extended to the open disk of radius $r$ centered at $0$. Moreover,
$$|v(z)-v(0)|\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|v^{(k)}(0)|}{k!}\,|z|^k
\le c\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{|z|}r\Big)^k=c\frac{|z|}{r-|z|}\le l/2$$
and hence
$$|v(z)|\ge l/2$$
for complex $z$ such that
$$|z|\le s:=\frac l{2c+l}\,r. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
So, for $u:=1/v$ we have $|u(z)|\le 2/l$ given \eqref{1}. So, by the Cauchy integral formula,
$$|u^{(k)}(0)|\le \frac2l\frac{k!}{s^k} $$
for $k=0,1,\dots$.
